# mdb_get from one process succeeds but fails from another long running process

Tags: lmdb

We have couple of processes A and B on an ARM device.
A is a long running process which will report the data from an lmdb.
Whenever there is a query, we do an mdb_get(key) and return the result.
mdb_get returns -30798.

Process B is a CLI tool to query the lmdb. mdb_get(key) on the same key works fine from the process.

one of the differences is process B is spawned, a txn is created, mdb_get() is called and the, aborts the txn and the process exits.

Both A and B open the lmdb with READ_ONLY.

I am able to step through the mdb_get () code. mdb_node_search fails in the process A whereas it succeeds in B. The number of keys is small - 20.

Can someone please help on what things I can check in mdb?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-30798 is MDB_NOTFOUND error.

Is hard to answer your question with further data.
Is your db completely static ? No other processes make changes/insertions/deletions ?

Should I guess an answer you're in a situation like this one:

- Process A starts its own transaction (and reader) so it has an "image" of the data at the moment process starts
- Another process somewhere puts new data into database using another transaction
- Process A will never see new data unless it aborts and restarts a new transaction

The fact process B (the CLI tool) always works is easy to understand : at the moment of execution it starts a new transaction which has the "latest image from all previous committed transactions".

Comment: Right, Thanks.

Process A also starts a new trasnaction every time it attempts a read and then commits the transaction after the read is finished.